# Transferring items from one listBox to another list

Tags: vb.net

i have ListBox1 and ListBox2 and textbox

I want the following when setting a value in a TextBox. If the value in ListBox is1, then items are moved from the current value to the last items in not the first. to listbox2

[image]

```
Dim foo As String
Dim index As Integer = 0
Dim good As Integer = 0
foo = TextBox1.Text
ListBox2.Items.Clear()

For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    If ListBox1.Items(i).ToString = foo Then
        index = i
    End If
    If i >= index Then
        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items(good).ToString)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Does the code work?  Are there errors?  What do you need help with?

Comment: Does the code work? Are there errors? What do you need help with? The code does not work

Comment: I'm trying to get you to improve your question.  Are there errors?  What does "code not work" mean?  `good  = 0` seems to always be zero.  Probably not what you intended.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger to step through your code as it runs.  You can examine the values during the loop.  You will quickly see `i >= index` is true every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As Lars has noted in a comment, the index is 0 at the beginning so the condition `i >= index` wil be always true. So you need to intialize it with `Int32.MaxValue`.
2. You add always the first item, because `good` is always 0. You should use the loop variable `i`:

   ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString())

---

Here is a LINQ version which simplifies the whole code, you don't need more:

```
ListBox2.Items.Clear()
Dim allAfter = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object).SkipWhile(Function(item) Not TextBox1.Text.Equals(item))
ListBox2.Items.AddRange(allAfter.ToArray())
```

Comment: `index` is zero, so his condition `If i >= index Then` will always be true.  Doesn't matter what's in the box.

Comment: @LarsTech: You're right. Edited the answer